# VS2015 sharing projects between solutions seems to extend build times unnecessarily

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

We have several (around 10) C++ DLL projects that are shared between several solutions.

My (possibly naive) belief is that if I'm building each solution consecutively - after the first solution's build, the rest should build very quickly. This is (thankfully) true for the 'compiling code' stuff, but something doesn't seem quite right as the compiler/linker still does some work that seems unnecessary.

To simplify the problem I've created two solutions that share an effectively empty win32 DLL project. After each build I get the following ('normal' verbosity output - I'll spare you the 'detailed' and 'diagnostic', for now):

```
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>         Creating "Debug\Prj_1.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild" because "AlwaysCreate" was specified.
1>       ClCompile:
1>         All outputs are up-to-date.
1>         All outputs are up-to-date.
1>       Link:
1>         All outputs are up-to-date.
1>         Prj_1.vcxproj -> E:\code\C++\CommonLibTest\CLT_1\Debug\Prj_1.dll
1>         Prj_1.vcxproj -> E:\code\C++\CommonLibTest\CLT_1\Debug\Prj_1.pdb (Full PDB)
1>       FinalizeBuildStatus:
1>         Deleting file "Debug\Prj_1.tlog\unsuccessfulbuild".
1>         Touching "Debug\Prj_1.tlog\Prj_1.lastbuildstate".
```

It's the 'link' step that concerns me - in particular the `(Full PDB)`. This isn't significant in the test situation, but when building our larger solutions it tends to add an annoying amount of time to the build process (a build that 'should' take a couple seconds ends up taking around a minute).

With 'detailed' build output I see the following message:

> Forcing rebuild of all source files due to a change in the command
>   line since the last build.

I've seen other posts on this site relating to this message, but nothing mentioned in these has helped me.

I've tried the above simple test case with and without precompiled-headers, with no change in behaviour.

My only solution is to change the intermediate directory to be a subfolder in the solution's output-folder. This isn't ideal, though, as you then have to build each project in isolation... which ends up taking much longer.